# Are Google App Engine channels reuseable?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, channel-api

I am looking into the possibility of using Google App Engine for a java app but need something like WebSockets. It seems that initially Google App Engine's channels supported reuse. But various posts around at least 2013 seemed to suggest that this doesn't work anymore. Now in 2016 can anyone verify whether or not reuse works?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by reusable?

Comment: @Nick a channel is suppose to be good for only a one user connection. If say the user disconnects he cannot reconnect to the same channel. The google app engine webapp needs to create a new channel. This is problematic because channels are expensive and so not a substitute for websockets.

Comment: It sounds by 'reusable' you're asking if a disconnected channel can be reconnected. This does not happen. A new channel needs to be established using the js api. Channels also only last about 20 minutes, and need to be reconnected periodically. Channels are also uni-directional, unlike websockets. If you need a realtime data feed from the server, they're great, easy to set up and use and scale well. If you're after something more complicated, you may need another solution.

Comment: @Nick From where did you get the information of 20 minutes period, is it documented somewhere or your experience ?

Comment: Just previous experience, and may no longer be true. I would recommend testing. The docs state that the duration matches that of the duration requested when the token is generated, its probably better for people to rely on that then my comment above.